# estructura de onsumit en llamado a método de controlador Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

hola estoy realizando la llamada al método de mi controlador, esto funcionaba bien realizaba el proceso

```
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'question.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
```

pero tenia que realizar una acción después de guardar los datos, por lo que realice una función JS y la mando ejecutar de la siguiente forma

```
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'question.store','method'=>'POST', 'onsubmit' => 'cerrarModCuest(); return false;')) !!}
```

realiza la acción que quiero que realice después de guardar PERO ahora me omitió la acción de guardar no ejecuta el método guardar solo la acción secundaria. 
¿que estoy realizando mal?

Comment: Hola pudiste solucionar tu problema? Tal vez puedas dar mayor información para poder apoyarte.

Comment: si retire el return false y funciono a medias, ya que no puedo hacer que se recargue la pagina a la que regreso para que cargue las opciones posteriores.